# Compile error when creating two classes, each of which contains a member function to access the other class

Tags: c++

I want to create two classes, each of which contains a member function that can access the private member in the other class. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B;

class A {
    int a;
public:
    void init();
    void printB(B*);
    friend void B::printA(A*);
};

class B {
    int b;
public:
    void init();
    void printA(A*);
    friend void A::printB(B*);
};

void A::init() {
    a = 10;
}

void A::printB(B* bp) {
    cout << bp->b << endl;
}

void B::init() {
    b = 999;
}

void B::printA(A* ap) {
    cout << ap->a << endl;
}

int main() {
    A x;
    B y;
    x.init();
    y.init();
    x.printB(&y);
    y.printA(&x);
}
```

When compiling with `g++`, I got the error

```
twoclassTest.cpp:11:26: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class B’
twoclassTest.cpp:4:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class B’
twoclassTest.cpp: In member function ‘void B::printA(A*)’:
twoclassTest.cpp:7:6: error: ‘int A::a’ is private
twoclassTest.cpp:35:14: error: within this context
```

It seems that the compiler don't know what's exactly in `class B` when it saw

```
friend void B::printA(A*)
```

I can't figure out the solution to this problem, so I have to rewrite `class A` like this

```
class A {
        int a;
public:
        void init();
        void printB(B*);
        friend class B;
};
```

This worked, but actually I don't want every member function of `B` to be able to access the private member in `A`. So is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Why are you doing this to yourself?

Comment: @Jefffrey an exercise problem that I saw, and I want to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

At the point when it reaches:

```
friend void B::printA(A*);
```

The compile cannot know that `B` has a member function `printA`. That's what is causing the error. The best solution is to decouple those two classes and remove the dependency altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeffery says, the trouble is that the compiler has no way of knowing that `B::printA()` exists at the point at which you try and declare it as a friend.

If you really want to do things this way, you can get around it by declaring the whole of class `B` as a friend of `A`, i.e. replace `friend void B::printA(A*)` with `friend class B`.

I think the moral of this story though is "if it hurts, don't do it"! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a 'thing' is a class. In this case, the interface between `A` and `B` can be represented as a class `Shared`.

Of course, you could go even further and define two interfaces, `ASharedWithB` and `BSharedWithA`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A;
class B;

class Shared
{
public:
    static void print(A* a);
    static void print(B* b);
};

class B;

class A {
    int a;
public:
    void init();
    void printB(B*);
    friend class Shared;
};

class B {
    int b;
public:
    void init();
    void printA(A*);
    friend class Shared;
};

void A::init() {
    a = 10;
}

void A::printB(B* bp) {
    Shared::print(bp);
}

void B::init() {
    b = 999;
}

void B::printA(A* ap) {
    Shared::print(ap);
}

void Shared::print(A* ap)
{
    cout << ap->a << endl;
}

void Shared::print(B* bp)
{
    cout << bp->b << endl;
}

int main() {
    A x;
    B y;
    x.init();
    y.init();
    x.printB(&y);
    y.printA(&x);
}
```

Comment: Why use a class with only static members, rather than free functions (in a private namespace if necessary)? The end result is the same, but free functions give you more fine-grained control over friendship.

Comment: As stated, using `class` to represent the `thing` being abstracted is a standard pattern. In this specific case, that would allow the `Shared` interface to be extended to also have a handle to the original implicit member should that be required to determine the implementation of the `print` class.